# Responsive blank image overlay for an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to find a javascript solution where it dynamically overlay a blank image similar to David Walsh's dwImageProtector Plugin (http://davidwalsh.name/image-protector-plugin-for-jquery). My problem with that plugin is, first, it append the overlay to the 'body' which actually don't align to the targeted image and second, that plugin is not built for responsive, meaning if I adjust the width of my browser the overlay image will stay the same way as the original parsed image size.

my code look something like this:

```
//css
.column { position: relative }
.column img { width: 100%; }


// html
<div class='column'>
    <img class='protect' src='img/source.jpg' />
    <span>copyright 2013</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate these "image protector" techniques, because they're annoying for those with legitimate reason to download the image, and easily circumvented for those without. It's like locking the front door of your house while leaving all the windows unsecured; the "protection" provided is nothing but a lie.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yeah, I get what you mean. They can always do a screenshot of the image if they really want to. But i'm trying to reduce the amount of people downloading/stealing the image without any permission. If you a better idea or technique, I'd be happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** The overlay trick only deters at best the uninitiated visitors who want to steal your images. There is no feasible way of detering thefts because:

1. Visitors can check the image source from Inspector, and download it directly (but you can circumvent that using .htaccess rules that prevents direct file access)
2. Visitors can hide the image overlay
3. Visitors can take a screenshot of the page
4. Visitors can sniff files that are served from the server to their browser

---

**Back to my solution:** You don't actually need to use JavaScript (or jQuery) for this purpose. A simple CSS trick using pseudo-elements will work. Let's say you have the following markup:

```
<div class='column'>
    <div class='protect'>
        <img src='img/source.jpg' />
    </div>
    <span>copyright 2013</span>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
.protect {
    position: relative;
}
.protect:after {
    background-image: url(/path/to/overlay);
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

If you can't change the markup, though, then you should rely on using jQuery to wrap your image element with a `<div class="protect">` element, and apply the same styles as mentioned above, i.e.

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="protect" />');
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks again. Yeah i'm a aware there are various ways a person can extract the image. I'm just trying to reduce the number as much as possible. Thanks again, Terry.

Comment: You can also add `pointer-events: none` to the `<img>` element to prevent cursor events being triggered from it (e.g. right clicking wouldn't work), although it can be easily circumvented by disabling the property in Inspector or the likes.